# Transparent Bootstrap Panel

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, opacity, transparent

I have picked [this free bootstrap theme](http://bootswatch.com/slate/), and my problem is that I want to create transparent panels, but when I set `opacity: 0.8;` the text in the panel, of course, gets transparent, which is not something I would like to happen. I tried using this CSS code, but it looks like there is still something behind the heading and body and the panel doesn't become transparent.

```
.panel-transparent .panel-heading{
    background: rgba(122, 130, 136, 0.2)!important;
}

.panel-transparent .panel-body{
    background: rgba(46, 51, 56, 0.2)!important;
}
```

Sample HTML:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Panel primary</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    Panel content
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**CSS**

```
    body {
        background:#c33;
    }

    .panel-transparent {
        background: none;
    }

    .panel-transparent .panel-heading{
        background: rgba(122, 130, 136, 0.2)!important;
    }

    .panel-transparent .panel-body{
        background: rgba(46, 51, 56, 0.2)!important;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="panel panel-primary panel-transparent">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Panel primary</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    Panel content
  </div>
</div>
```

[Example](http://www.bootply.com/kwRhQoQb7j)

Comment: You could also add the footer in case in the future you are going to use it! `.panel-transparent .panel-footer{
        background: rgba(46, 51, 56, 0.2)!important;
    }`

Answer (score 2):

```css
.transparent{    
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
}

.panel{
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px #222;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-default">
     <div class="panel-heading">Título</div>
     <div class="panel-body transparent">                  
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply go for "bg-transparent" as mentioned in the link above;
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/colors/

Such;

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title bg-transparent text-dark">Panel primary</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body bg-transparent text-white">
    Panel content
  </div>
</div>
```

And definitely be sure not to forget adding bootstrap.

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.