# Bootstrap transparent panel css background: rgba won't get transparent

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make the default panel of bootstrap transparent and tried it with the answer i found here ([Transparent Bootstrap Panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24855438/transparent-bootstrap-panel)), by adding the following code to my stylesheet and then adding the `panel-transparent` class to my panel.

CSS:

```css
.panel-transparent {
 background: none;
}
.panel-transparent .panel-heading {
 background: rgba(122, 130, 136, 0.2)!important;
}
.panel-transparent .panel-body {
 background: rgba(46, 51, 56, 0.2)!important;
}
.panel {
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 background-color: #fff;
 border: 1px solid transparent;
 border-radius: 4px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
          box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}
.panel-body {
 padding: 15px;
}
.panel-heading {
 padding: 10px 15px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
 border-top-left-radius: 3px;
 border-top-right-radius: 3px;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="panel panel-default panel-transparent">
  <div class="panel-heading">
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <h3 id="fahrzeugwahlh3">Heading:</h3>
    <p id="fahrzeugwahltext">Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Somehow the panel gets the desired color but it's not transparent and i don't know what i am doing wrong.

See here: https://jsfiddle.net/ktLypzgr/

**Solution:**

Had my Stylesheets linked in a wrong order, so that they got overwritten!

Sometimes its as simple as this...
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please share your code..

Comment: @dhavalraythatha ..did

Comment: Please show _testable_ code. This is a client-side problem, so any server-side code is uninteresting. Remove anything that is PHP, and show the _complete_ HTML code necessary to test this - preferably online somewhere. [mcve]

Comment: its working good .. i have check the code

Comment: " See here: https://jsfiddle.net/ktLypzgr/ " — It **is** transparent. If you change the 0.2 to a 1 then it becomes darker because the white background is no longer visible through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.panel-transparent {
    background: none;
}`

removes only the `background-image` property. Also add `transparent` after the `none` value.

Comment: Also did not do its job...

Comment: then your styles are overwritten by some other inherited styles.

Comment: Your `.panel` rules ar overwriting the `.panel-transparent` class, because it's declared after the transparent class.

Comment: THANKS! Had my Stylesheets linked in a wrong order so they would be overwritten!

Answer (score 0):

try this

check demo **[here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mAmapk?editors=1100)**

```css
body {
  background: red;
}
.panel-transparent {
  background: transparent;
}
.panel-transparent .panel-heading {
  background: rgba(122, 130, 136, 0.2)!important;
}
.panel-transparent .panel-body {
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-default panel-transparent">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <?php showWebiscoWidget(KNR, 'Widget', array( 'layout'=>'layout')); ?>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <h3 id="fahrzeugwahlh3">Heading:</h3>
    <p id="fahrzeugwahltext">Text</p>
    <?php showWebiscoWidget( KNR, 'Widget' ); ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sadly still not transparent...

Comment: please check the updated answer and to make rgba transparent set alpha value to 0.