# Want to make text div transparent on a parallax area

Tags: html, css, alpha-transparency

I am trying to make a text div transparent on a parallax area.

Here is my code:

```html
<div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top:0px;margin_bottom:0px;background-color:#ffffff;padding:0;margin:0">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" style="background-image: url('http://localhost:8000/images/pages/parallax/1561656567.jpg');min-height: 500px;background-attachment: fixed;background-position: center;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: cover;">
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-md-12" style="padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;min-height:500px;background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.1);color:#000000;">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nec ei illud everti pericula, cu eos labitur lucilius. Illum debet tincidunt ne cum, eu oratio melius impedit duo, ad quem ancillae quaerendum sit. Qui ne choro graecis adipiscing, vidisse petentium at mei. Quo an porro
          congue eirmod, eam an probo nihil, nominati forensibus ut eos. Has te saperet epicuri adversarium, sint cibo explicari ad cum. Vis argumentum consequuntur id, eum lorem evertitur ei, vim mollis signiferumque concludaturque ei.</p>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nec ei illud everti pericula, cu eos labitur lucilius. Illum debet tincidunt ne cum, eu oratio melius impedit duo, ad quem ancillae quaerendum sit. Qui ne choro graecis adipiscing, vidisse petentium at mei. Quo an porro
          congue eirmod, eam an probo nihil, nominati forensibus ut eos. Has te saperet epicuri adversarium, sint cibo explicari ad cum. Vis argumentum consequuntur id, eum lorem evertitur ei, vim mollis signiferumque concludaturque ei.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The lower container's background colour is always coming up as solid.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The lower container is a child of that `div.container-fluid` element, whose background color is set: `background-color:#ffffff;`
The lower container may be transparent, but what you see beneath it is that parent element with a solid background.

Comment: I've changed the top div to:

`<div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top:0px;margin_bottom:0px;padding:0;margin:0">`

but still the same

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OeZOwj

Looks transparent to me

Comment: Thanks. The problem seems to be something to do with Bootstrap. Looking at their css I found that there is a definition in container-fluid of 
  `background-color: #fff;` so I removed it. I can't see anywhere that the body is set to white but it still does not work.

Comment: Hunting around I found that something similar has been queried before, but with no answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24855438/transparent-bootstrap-panel

Comment: You can make it transparent by adding `background: transparent;` or `background: rgba(x, x, x, 0);` (where x is any integer). [Check this out](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QXVBPp)

Answer (score 2):

Try this, I hope this is what you are looking for

```css
      body {
          background: #e5e5e5;
          padding:0px;
          margin:0px;
        }
```

```html
        <div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top:0px;margin_bottom:0px;background-color:transparent;padding:0;margin:0">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12" style="background-image: url('https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0301/0065/files/fall_background_image_landscape_tree_lake_mountain_scene_web_2048x2048.jpg');min-height: 500px;background-attachment: fixed;background-position: center;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: cover;">
            </div>
            <div class="container">
              <div class="col-md-12" style="padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;min-height:500px;background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0);color:#000000;">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nec ei illud everti pericula, cu eos labitur lucilius. Illum debet tincidunt ne cum, eu oratio melius impedit duo, ad quem ancillae quaerendum sit. Qui ne choro graecis adipiscing, vidisse petentium at mei. Quo an porro
                  congue eirmod, eam an probo nihil, nominati forensibus ut eos. Has te saperet epicuri adversarium, sint cibo explicari ad cum. Vis argumentum consequuntur id, eum lorem evertitur ei, vim mollis signiferumque concludaturque ei.</p>

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nec ei illud everti pericula, cu eos labitur lucilius. Illum debet tincidunt ne cum, eu oratio melius impedit duo, ad quem ancillae quaerendum sit. Qui ne choro graecis adipiscing, vidisse petentium at mei. Quo an porro
                  congue eirmod, eam an probo nihil, nominati forensibus ut eos. Has te saperet epicuri adversarium, sint cibo explicari ad cum. Vis argumentum consequuntur id, eum lorem evertitur ei, vim mollis signiferumque concludaturque ei.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check if this is what you are looking for:

https://codepen.io/furqanrahamath94/pen/XLxvjE

A scrollable semi-transparent div block with fixed image in the background.

Here is my modified two classes:

```
.image {
    background: url(http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5104/5862419072_7f9632f068_b.jpg) no-repeat fixed;
    background-position: center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 500px;
    position: fixed; // <-- Making it fixed in position
    width: 100%;
}
.content {
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0 2rem;                     // <-- Adding padding for nicer view
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) // <-- Semi transparent background
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the white div is not passing over the image, it is pushing the div with the image background, they are not overlapping as they are siblings with relative positions.

If you assign an image background to the container you will achieve the result you are asking for:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top:0px;margin_bottom:0px;background-color:#ffffff;padding:0;margin:0">

      <!-- background image is here, on the row -->
      <div class="row" style="background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/500/sports/');min-height: 500px;background-attachment: fixed;background-position: center;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: cover;">

        <div class="container">
          <div class="col-md-12" style="padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;min-height:500px;background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.1);color:#000000;">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nec ei illud everti pericula, cu eos labitur lucilius. Illum debet tincidunt ne cum, eu oratio melius impedit duo, ad quem ancillae quaerendum sit. Qui ne choro graecis adipiscing, vidisse petentium at mei. Quo an porro
              congue eirmod, eam an probo nihil, nominati forensibus ut eos. Has te saperet epicuri adversarium, sint cibo explicari ad cum. Vis argumentum consequuntur id, eum lorem evertitur ei, vim mollis signiferumque concludaturque ei.</p>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nec ei illud everti pericula, cu eos labitur lucilius. Illum debet tincidunt ne cum, eu oratio melius impedit duo, ad quem ancillae quaerendum sit. Qui ne choro graecis adipiscing, vidisse petentium at mei. Quo an porro
              congue eirmod, eam an probo nihil, nominati forensibus ut eos. Has te saperet epicuri adversarium, sint cibo explicari ad cum. Vis argumentum consequuntur id, eum lorem evertitur ei, vim mollis signiferumque concludaturque ei.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this but it is not quite what I want to achieve. If you look at https://codepen.io/paulomrcunha/pen/dHscj you will see what I am getting at the moment. I want the background colour of the text pan which is white (in that example) to be able to be controlled via its opacity, so in theory it could be transparent/

Comment: I see always the same problem here: your elements never overlap and it is impossible to see the background image of an element that is not there. To see the image behind you need to set background image to a parent element, not to a sibling (unless you want to use absolute positioning). Look here: https://codepen.io/DanieleAlessandra/pen/MMPjyr

Comment: To be more clear, here is your example with only colored outline added: https://codepen.io/DanieleAlessandra/pen/VJEKmo - The green border is the limit of the div with class=image you cannot see the background image of that div outside that border. The red line is the border of the element with .content class.

Answer (score 0):

use background image on parent div. Hope it will fix the problem.

```
<div class="container-fluid"  style="background-image: url('https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0301/0065/files/fall_background_image_landscape_tree_lake_mountain_scene_web_2048x2048.jpg');min-height: 500px;background-attachment: fixed;background-position: center;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: cover;" style="margin-top:0px;margin_bottom:0px;padding:0;margin:0">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-md-12" style="padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;min-height:500px;color:#000000;">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nec ei illud everti pericula, cu eos labitur lucilius. Illum debet tincidunt ne cum, eu oratio melius impedit duo, ad quem ancillae quaerendum sit. Qui ne choro graecis adipiscing, vidisse petentium at mei. Quo an porro
          congue eirmod, eam an probo nihil, nominati forensibus ut eos. Has te saperet epicuri adversarium, sint cibo explicari ad cum. Vis argumentum consequuntur id, eum lorem evertitur ei, vim mollis signiferumque concludaturque ei.</p>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nec ei illud everti pericula, cu eos labitur lucilius. Illum debet tincidunt ne cum, eu oratio melius impedit duo, ad quem ancillae quaerendum sit. Qui ne choro graecis adipiscing, vidisse petentium at mei. Quo an porro
          congue eirmod, eam an probo nihil, nominati forensibus ut eos. Has te saperet epicuri adversarium, sint cibo explicari ad cum. Vis argumentum consequuntur id, eum lorem evertitur ei, vim mollis signiferumque concludaturque ei.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of giving *backgroud-image* to `div` you should give it to the `body`!
 Also change `rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)`, `margin-top:50%` and `padding:12px` of text `div`.

```html
<body style="background-image: url('https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0301/0065/files/fall_background_image_landscape_tree_lake_mountain_scene_web_2048x2048.jpg');min-height: 500px;background-attachment: fixed;background-position: center;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: cover;">
<div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top:0px;margin_bottom:0px;padding:0;margin:0">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" >
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-md-12" style="padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;min-height:500px;background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);margin-top:50%;padding:12px">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nec ei illud everti pericula, cu eos labitur lucilius. Illum debet tincidunt ne cum, eu oratio melius impedit duo, ad quem ancillae quaerendum sit. Qui ne choro graecis adipiscing, vidisse petentium at mei. Quo an porro
          congue eirmod, eam an probo nihil, nominati forensibus ut eos. Has te saperet epicuri adversarium, sint cibo explicari ad cum. Vis argumentum consequuntur id, eum lorem evertitur ei, vim mollis signiferumque concludaturque ei.</p>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nec ei illud everti pericula, cu eos labitur lucilius. Illum debet tincidunt ne cum, eu oratio melius impedit duo, ad quem ancillae quaerendum sit. Qui ne choro graecis adipiscing, vidisse petentium at mei. Quo an porro
          congue eirmod, eam an probo nihil, nominati forensibus ut eos. Has te saperet epicuri adversarium, sint cibo explicari ad cum. Vis argumentum consequuntur id, eum lorem evertitur ei, vim mollis signiferumque concludaturque ei.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Hope this helps!